Quarkus - get an access to Jandex index
I'm new to the subject of Quarkus. How can I use Jandex index in a java class? I added a goal to the maven to build index, then I created a class but don't know go how to use it? I can create a index by using Indexer but then I need to decalare all classes to scan. How can I solve it better?
private void testIndex() {
        Indexer indexer = new Indexer();
        try
        {
            indexer.indexClass( MyClass.class );
            Collection< ClassInfo > knownClasses = indexer.complete()
                .getKnownClasses();
        }
        catch( IOException e )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }


In Quarkus, Jandex is typically used at build time, in extensions. See https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension or https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-extensions. In a @BuildStep method, you can declare a parameter of type e.g. CombinedIndexBuildItem and obtain a Jandex index from there. If you want to use Jandex in application runtime, there's nothing Quarkus can do for you.

This is not my case. I need to get to the index in the filter for the AsyncAPI that declares .property. It can't be BuildStep.
I need to access exactly here:
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-asyncapi/blob/main/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner-tests/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner-tests-
simple/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/asyncapi/annotation/scanner/MyAsyncApiFilter.java

The Jandex index is generated at build time, so your best bet is to write a Quarkus extension, which can participate in the build process. In your extension's processor, you can declare Build Step methods with arguments. Quarkus will automatically invoke your build steps with the arguments of the type you request.
So, to get a Jandex, index, you could write a method in your extension processor something like this:
   @BuildStep
    void doAThingWithTheIndex(ApplicationIndexBuildItem applicationIndex,
            CombinedIndexBuildItem combinedIndex) {
        ...
    }

See also:

A tutorial on setting up an extension
A list of available build items
An article explaining how to use a Jandex index in an extension to transform out some problematic annotations


This is not my case. I need to get to the index in the filter for the AsyncAPI that declares .property. It can't be BuildStep.
I need to access exactly here:
https://github.com/quarkiverse/quarkus-asyncapi/blob/main/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner-tests/quarkus-asyncapi-scanner-tests-
simple/src/main/java/io/quarkiverse/asyncapi/annotation/scanner/MyAsyncApiFilter.java

You're already using an extension, so that's a good start. One option is to use a BuildItem to grab the index, and pass it to another part of your codebase.
If you only want the index in tests, to validate your extension is working as expected, you might be better off trying to use something that isn't Jandex. That would give you the most 'independent' validation.

Finally I went into direction of own extension like you suggested.
